# How can I split the data into test and train without using function train_test_split?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

i am currently working on timeseries forecasting, and I have to split the data into a training set and a test set. (Have the first 70% of the data be in the training set)

However, i cannot use the train_test_split function because it will shuffle the rows. How else I can split the data

Comment: Do you have an ID of which is train and which is test? if not, is it just that you need the first 70% of your data to be training and the rest is for testing?

Comment: yep it's just i need to make the first 70% as my training.

Comment: Hi Cookie Monster, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use  train_test_split , but setting `shuffle = False`

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html